# getting records which are different from two fastq files

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have 2 fastq files F1.fastq and F2.fastq. F2.fastq is a smaller file which is a subset of reads from F1.fastq. I want reads in F1.fastq which ARE NOT in F2.fastq. The following python code does not seem to work. Can you suggest edits?

```
needed_reads = []

reads_array = []

chosen_array = []

for x in Bio.SeqIO.parse("F1.fastq","fastq"):

        reads_array.append(x)

for y in Bio.SeqIO.parse("F2.fastq","fastq"):

        chosen_array.append(y)

for y in chosen_array:

        for x in reads_array:

                if str(x.seq) != str(y.seq) : needed_reads.append(x)

output_handle = open("DIFF.fastq","w")

SeqIO.write(needed_reads,output_handle,"fastq")

output_handle.close()
```

Comment: cross-posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/147317/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sets for accomplishing your requirement , you can convert `list1` to `set` and then `list2` to `set` , and then do `set(list1) - set(list2)` , it will give items in `list1` that are not in `list2` .

Sample code -

```
needed_reads = []

reads_array = []

chosen_array = []

for x in Bio.SeqIO.parse("F1.fastq","fastq"):

        reads_array.append(x)

for y in Bio.SeqIO.parse("F2.fastq","fastq"):

        chosen_array.append(y)

needed_reads = list(set(reads_array) - set(chosen_array))

output_handle = open("DIFF.fastq","w")

SeqIO.write(needed_reads,output_handle,"fastq")

output_handle.close()
```

Comment: This does not work, DIFF.fastq seems to be the same as F1.fastq

Comment: Are you sure there are common values in between them?

Comment: yes, the DIFF.fastq file has records from the F2.fastq file also

Comment: can you try deleting the DIFF.fastq file if you do not need it, and try running the exact code i pasted above, I am not getting any issues in set difference , it does not give me any values from list2 at all

Comment: I tried this and now it works, I think it was appending to the DIFF file before