# Getting reads from one fastq file that are not found in another fastq file

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, fastq

I would like to get a fastq file comprised of fastq reads that are in `F1.fastq` but are not in `F2.fastq`.

The following code was offered as a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942734/getting-records-which-are-different-from-two-fastq-files).

```
needed_reads = []
reads_array = []
chosen_array = []

for x in SeqIO.parse("F1.fastq","fastq"):
    reads_array.append(x)

for y in SeqIO.parse("F2.fastq","fastq"):
    chosen_array.append(y)

needed_reads = list(set(reads_array) - set(chosen_array))

output_handle = open("DIFF.fastq","w")
SeqIO.write(needed_reads,output_handle,"fastq")
output_handle.close()
```

However, it no longer works and produces a `"unhashable type: SeqRecord"` error when the `set()` function is run on the output of `SeqIO.parse()`. `SeqIO.parse()` still produces a list type object according to the `type()` function. However, that list appears to be unhashable. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, instead of `BioPython`, use `seqtk` and UNIX tools, as shown here:

[How to remove a list of reads from fastq file?](https://www.biostars.org/p/199946/)

First, use `grep` to extract read ids from fastq file. Use `comm` to extract only the read names to keep:

```
comm -23 <( cat test2.1.fastq | paste - - - - | grep -Po '^@\K\S+' | sort ) <( cat test1.1.fastq | paste - - - - | grep -Po '^@\K\S+' | sort ) > name.lst
```

To extract reads from fastq files by IDs, use [`seqtk subseq`](https://github.com/lh3/seqtk):

```
seqtk subseq test2.1.fastq name.lst > out.fastq
```

It works with `fasta` files as well.

Alternatively, use [`BBMap filterbyname.sh`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bbmap/), see [docs](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=58221):

> By default, "filterbyname" discards reads with names in your name list, and keeps the rest. To include them and discard the others, do this:
> `filterbyname.sh in=003.fastq out=filter003.fq names=names003.txt include=t`

**See also:**

- [Extracting specific sequences from FASTQ using Seqtk](https://www.biostars.org/p/342043/)
- [How To Extracting Fastq Sequence For Given Fastq Ids And Fastq File](https://www.biostars.org/p/74243/)
- [How To Extract A Subset Of Reads In Fastq Using An Id List?](https://www.biostars.org/p/45816/)

To install these tools, use `conda`, specifically `miniconda`, for example:

```
conda create --channel bioconda --name seqtk seqtk
conda activate seqtk
# ... use seqtk here ...
conda deactivate
```

Here, GNU `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.

**See also:**

- [GNU `grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
- [perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)
- [`seqtk`](https://github.com/lh3/seqtk)
- [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html)
- [`conda create`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html)

**Files used in the above example:**

```
cat test1.1.fastq
@M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10001:20001/1
ACGTAACCGGTTAAACCCGGGTTTAAAACCCCGGGGTTTTAAAAACCCCCGGGGGTTTTTAAAAAACCCCCCGGG
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10002:20002/1
GGGTTTTTTAAAAAAACCCCCCCGGGGGGGTTTTTTTAAAAAAAACCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGTTTTTTTTAAAAAA
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

```
cat test2.1.fastq
@M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10001:20001/1
ACGTAACCGGTTAAACCCGGGTTTAAAACCCCGGGGTTTTAAAAACCCCCGGGGGTTTTTAAAAAACCCCCCGGG
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10002:20002/1
GGGTTTTTTAAAAAAACCCCCCCGGGGGGGTTTTTTTAAAAAAAACCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGTTTTTTTTAAAAAA
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10003:20003/1
ACGTAACCGGTTAAACCCGGGTTTAAAACCCCGGGGTTTTAAAAACCCCCGGGGGTTTTTAAAAAACCCCCCGGG
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10004:20004/1
GGGTTTTTTAAAAAAACCCCCCCGGGGGGGTTTTTTTAAAAAAAACCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGTTTTTTTTAAAAAA
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

```
cat name.lst
M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10003:20003/1
M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10004:20004/1
```

```
cat out.fastq
@M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10003:20003/1
ACGTAACCGGTTAAACCCGGGTTTAAAACCCCGGGGTTTTAAAAACCCCCGGGGGTTTTTAAAAAACCCCCCGGG
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
@M01873:M01873:000000000-B4TLH:1:1101:10004:20004/1
GGGTTTTTTAAAAAAACCCCCCCGGGGGGGTTTTTTTAAAAAAAACCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGTTTTTTTTAAAAAA
+
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Answer (score 1):

say two fastq reads are the same if they share the same NAME:

linearize with `paste`,
`join` on NAME,
restore the fastq format with `tr`

something like (not tested)

```
 join -t $'\t' -v1 -1 1 -2 1 \
      <(cat F1.fastq | paste - - - - | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1) \
      <(cat F2.fastq | paste - - - - | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1) |\
 tr "\t" "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the BioPython documentation tells you, they changed how `SeqRecord` objects are compared. (This is what `SeqIO` returns when you loop over it.) It's really a question of what exactly you want to compare.

Here is a refactoring which checks if the actual sequence is identical, and if so, skips the ones which are already in the smaller file.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

chosen_seqs = [y.seq for y in SeqIO.parse("F2.fastq", "fastq")]
needed_reads = []

for x in SeqIO.parse("F1.fastq", "fastq"):
    if x.seq not in chosen_seqs:
        needed_reads.append(x)

with open("DIFF.fastq", "w") as output_handle:
    SeqIO.write(needed_reads,output_handle, "fastq")
```

This is slightly refactored to avoid keeping all the information in memory; you only need to have the smaller set in memory and then iterate over the bigger one one item at a time.

To change the selection logic, change `y.seq` to whichever feature you want to examine from the smaller file, and correspondingly change `x.seq` to whichever other feature you extracted from each `SeqRecord`.

---

From the entry for Biopython 1.67 (8 June 2016) from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biopython/biopython/master/NEWS.rst:

> Comparison of SeqRecord objects until now has used the default Python object
> comparison (are they the same instance in memory?). This can be surprising, but
> comparing all of the attributes would be too complex. As of this release
> attempting to compare SeqRecord objects should raise an exception instead. If
> you want the old behaviour, use `id(record1) == id(record2)` instead.